# I get error 405 when I tap Android Pay buy with now button?

Tags: android-pay

I'm trying to integrate Android Pay API with my mobile app.

I have production access for Android Pay.

In the checkout page, tapping Buy with Android Pay button I get the error code 405.

The following is the adb logcat:

```
: I/request/result code: requestCode: 66036, resultCode: 1 
: I/GWalletErrorCode: 405
: I/AdjustCallback: Activity Resumed
: I/request/result code: requestCode: 1001, resultCode: 1
: I/GWalletErrorCode: 405
:  I/AdjustCallback: Activity Resumed
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [WalletConstants](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants), the error code 405 is `ERROR_CODE_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_ERROR`.

As [explained here](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/deployment), this means you're trying to use Android Pay with the production environement, but your app is not signed with the correct key:

> When your app is pointed to the Android Pay production environment,
>   the Android Pay API returns `ERROR_CODE_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_ERROR (405)` if
>   the signing key fingerprint used to sign the Android app does not
>   match the release key fingerprint registered with Google Play. This
>   typically occurs after an app in development switches from the test
>   environment to the production environment